# jQuery and .length>0

Tags: jquery, coding-style

```
var sd = jQuery(".bla");
if (sd.length>0){

}
```

Is there any cooler way to write that code? I want some code to execute only if there are some classes named `bla`. I do know I can use the each, but I do not want to and I do know I can do stuff like `sd.action()`, but I do not want to.

Comment: You could remove the `>0` part.

Comment: .length is very cool imo. beauty in simplicity :)

Comment: `$` instead of `jQuery` is cooler.

Comment: True just because if (0) is false in javascript

Comment: And single quotes `'` are cooler than double quotes `"` imho.

Comment: And properly separating the tokens is cooler: `if ( sd.length > 0 ) {`

Comment: @Šime Vidas Why $ is cooler? because it won't work everywhere? less portable is cooler for you? I prefer more portable code.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what you want to do if the class exists? For example if you want to check on an element then if (element.hasClass("bla")) {} would work

Comment: @James Kyburz its a generic question, many times I want to do something with elements returned by the query and something extra with other objects.

Comment: @pimvdb that is a very cool idea :D

Comment: @IAdapter Well, it's cooler because it's shorter. Shorter code is always cooler. Where won't it work? Also, what do you mean by portability? Mobile devices?

Comment: Write it in Ruby. I've heard that's pretty cool.

Comment: @Šime Vidas when You use more than one JS framework the $ keyword is many times taken (You not always have a choice to use only one).

Comment: @IAdapter That is not an issue. You can pass the `$` name into the ready handler: `jQuery(function($) { ... use $ normally ... });`. Even if you don't use the ready handler, you can use an IIFE to do the same thing: `(function($) { ... use $ normally ... })(jQuery);`. You can read about this [in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Comment: @Šime Vidas so you are saying that "jQuery(function($) { ... use $ normally ... });" is better than just use jQuery instead of $? I kindda disagree. even for quick hacking the "jQuery" is much faster to use.

Comment: @IAdapter Of course I am saying that. The way I see it, using `jQuery` instead of just `$` is unreasonable. Why do you disagree? What's your argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how much 'cooler' this is, but just:

```
if ($('.bla').length) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Will do the trick.

**Edit**: If you need to re-use the selector after the check, you can still use the same syntax:

```
var sd = $(".bla");

if (sd.length) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: if I want to do something later with objects returned by query than its slower.

Answer (score 4):

To make the code look a little "cooler" if you don't want to use length etc..

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    exists: function() {
      return this.length !== 0;
    }
});

if (jQuery(".bla").exists()) {
  console.log('found');
}
```

Comment: Why not use `> 0`, saves two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this is a perfectly acceptable and fast way (no function calls) to do what you want.  I do similar things all the time.  Even using `$().each` is a little slower because it requires a function call, even though it won't actually *do* anything.

Regarding the other answer here, which is also correct:  Doing `$('.bla')` more than once will also be slower.  If you think you may use `$('.bla')` later, it's better to store it in a variable like you have in your code.  This avoids another jQuery call and lets the browser take care of the garbage collection.

Hope this makes sense! :)

Comment: This is true - if you're going to reuse the selector in other parts of your script then it is definitely more performant to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The "coolest" way to make that look (in my opinion) is

```
if ( $('.bla').length > 0 ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: if I want to do something later with objects returned by query than its slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .size()

$(".blah").size() > 0

http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Quote from that page: *"the .length property is preferred"*

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

I dont think there is anything cooler. (SO wouldnt let me just answer the question with No )